# How to build a form preferably in Gforms but any options are fine

Tags: google-sheets, forms, google-forms

I need to build a form and ill jump right in.
I have a job list j1 j2 j3 j4 j5 each job has a task associated, j1 has x j2 has xy j3 has xyz  j4 has xz and j5 has z

i want the user after selecting a job number ie. j1 and only have options x to pop up all while bouncing off of a database to update the form and associated dashboards as to restrict the user error as much as possible by filtering out options live.

we have tried to find an "off the shelf" form builder to accomplish this task but have fell short, if anyone has a solution to this problem that would be awesome!!

Comment: i dont need someone to build it i just need a route to take thanks guys!!

Comment: This doesn't look as a programming question. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].